# Singularity of Hankel Transform at $r=0$

Tags: statistical-mechanics, mathematical-physics, fourier-transform

I am working on using Fast Sine Transform to calculate the Hankel transform and its inverse with the Bessel Function of order 1/2.  $$F(k)=\frac{4\pi}{k}\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin(kr)rf(r)dr$$

$$f(r) = \frac{1}{2\pi^{2}r}\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin(kr)kF(k)dk$$

It looks like the inverse transform diverge at the point $$\lim_{r\to0} f(r) = \frac{1}{2\pi^{2}r}\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin(kr)kF(k)dk$$ Is this true? How do people calculate radial distribution function at $r=0$ from X-Ray diffraction data?

Comment: why do you say this diverges? for small $r$, $\sin kr/r \approx k$

Comment: What if I want to calculate exactly r=0? l'Hospital rule?

Comment: Look at the definition of $F(k)$, it is completely insensitive to the value of $f(0)$ since the rest of the integrand is 0 at $r=0$. It is only sensitive at how $f(r)$ evolves as $r \to 0$. So @NickP remarks is on the point here: the only meaningful way to get $f(0)$ is as the limit of $f(r)$: $f(0) \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} \frac{1}{2\pi^2}\int_0^{+\infty} k^2 F(k) dk$.

Comment: @LucJ.Bourhis  Thanks for the answer. This is what I had in mind too. But if I calculate $F(k)$ by Fast Sine Transform I would get $F(k)$ at finite $k$. However, I would need $F(k)$ at large $k$ or at infinite to calculate converged $f(0)$. The question is would a direct implementation of Fast Sine Transform and its inverse calculate a correct $f(0)$? I tried it first it did not work well.

Comment: I would say no, it won't work well, but isn't a problem greater than just $f(0)$? I mean FFT is designed for periodic signals, where the integrals would actually be over one period. Here you have to truncate for every value of $k$.

Comment: What if my $f(r)$ is periodic?